# SQL query SUM() AND GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MySQL table like this:

```
acco_id | room_id | arrival    | amount | persons | available
1       | 1       | 2015-19-12 | 3      | 4       | 1
1       | 2       | 2015-19-12 | 1      | 10      | 1
1       | 1       | 2015-26-12 | 4      | 4       | 1
1       | 2       | 2015-26-12 | 2      | 10      | 1
2       | 3       | 2015-19-12 | 2      | 6       | 0
2       | 4       | 2015-19-12 | 1      | 4       | 1
```

What im trying to achieve is a single query with a result like:

```
acco_id | max_persons_available
1       | 22
2       | 4
```

I tried using a GROUP BY accommodation_id using a query like:

```
SELECT 
    accommodation_id, 
    SUM(amount * persons) as max_persons_available 
FROM 
    availabilities 
WHERE 
    available = 1
GROUP BY 
    accommodation_id
```

Only now the result of acco_id uses all arrival dates. When I add arrival to the query no more unique acco_id's.

Does anyone know a good Single SQL which can use the table indexes?

Comment: How do you get `22` in `max_persons_available`? Shouldn't it be `20`?

Comment: `2015-26-12` — what kind of a date format is this?

Comment: so what you are saying is, that when you add arrival to your select, it is not grouped anymore ? .. What if you add GROUP BY accomodation_id, arrival ?

Comment: As per your problem definition, your query looks fine, can you re-check your query results.

Comment: A few things are unclear: What are the indexes? And do you mean that you want to limit it to certain arrival dates? And putting them into the where is having side effects?

Comment: @thomas yes that is what I meant. The GROUP BY adds all the results up, not for the single date.

Comment: @PeterSteenbergen if you want to limit it just to specific dates then my version could do that (my answer). you don't need to have the arrival date in the group by if you dont want it to be selected.   else if you also want it displyed DTHs answer just does that.

Comment: Ah indeed, Thanks Thomas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correct (the last part is a bit confusing). You want to have the accomodation id and numbers as you have now but limited to specific arrival dates.

If so the following statement should do exactly that as it is not necessary to put arrival into the select if you "just" use it in the where statement. As else you would need to put it into the group by and thus have non unique accomodation id's.

```
SELECT 
    accommodation_id, 
    SUM(amount * persons) as max_persons_available 
FROM 
    availabilities 
WHERE 
    available = 1 and arrival >= '2015-12-19' and arrival < '2015-10-26'
GROUP BY 
    accommodation_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess (reading your question) what you are looking for is this but im not sure as your question is a bit unclear:

```
SELECT 
    accommodation_id, 
    arrival,
    SUM(amount * persons) as max_persons_available 
FROM 
    availabilities 
WHERE 
    available = 1
GROUP BY 
    accommodation_id, arrival
```

Comment: From how I understand it he wants the accomidation to be unique and only limit it to certain arrival dates and that has side effects. But it is a bit confusingly written.

Comment: @Thomas My point exactly. I read it as if he can group when only selecting accomodation_id, but as soon as he adds arrival to the select its not grouped anymore .. So my answer above might cover that problem. IF thats the problem :)